# spring SPeL combine filter and projection operations

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Colleagues, how to combine together projection operator `![expr]`and filter `?[ boolean ]`.
For example I have some entity:

```
class User {
    int age;
    String name;
}
```

I would like select from list of Users only name of user who is elder than 30.

Standalone projection looks like:

```
#myArray.![name]
```

Standalone filtering looks like:

```
#myArray.?[age > 30]
```

So how to put it together? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(#myArray.?[age > 30]).![name]
```

i.e. perform the projection on the results of the selection.